# Can computer behind router connect to VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

In my company I have Netgear router which has build in VPN.
Now I have configured the settings on router.

IN my home I have one modem which is connected to router and then from router my computer.

I tried to install Netgear client software for VPN but it gives error like can configure adapter or could not find adapter.

What I want to ask is that can computer behind router can access VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not your router at home is set to restrict VPN traffic (usually PPTP, IPSec, or L2TP). Most consumer routers are set to allow this traffic by default.

Comment: I will try the software in window xp first if that installs correctly or not